# Using a local USB storage pen on a remote Windows server via Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, rdp, usb-flash-drive

Using the mstsc.exe client shipped by default with recent versions of Windows (i.e. Windows 7) is it possible to access local USB storage on a remote server (assume Windows Server 2008).

For example, I plug my USB key into my laptop, RDP onto a Windows 2008 server, and then I want to be able to access the USB key within the remote session and ideally copy files from the USB key to the remote server's file system?

Is this possible without any custom client software? I honestly thought this was possible but can't find the option anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. Click on options It's under the **local resources** tab... **Local Devices and resources**... click on the **More** button.

[image: Informative Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Chris's answer, after enabling local resources and connecting to the remote machine, you'll be able to access the local resources on the remote machine by typing in the Run window (Windows key + R) the following:

```
\\tsclient\Drive_letter
```

Answer (score 3):

An option not yet mentioned here would be to use the clipboard redirection, which is usually on by default and can be used even when the Remote Desktop server does not allow redirection of drives.

- connect to the Remote Desktop server
- minimize the session window
- open the Windows Explorer and navigate to the drive you want to copy data off
- select the files and folders you want to copy and copy them to the clipboard (e.g. by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)
- maximize your RD connection session window
- open the Windows Explorer and navigate to the destination folder you want to copy data to
- paste from the clipboard (e.g. by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just enable disk sharing in the RDP client prior to connecting to the server.